# how to access private class list?

Tags: c++

i dont know this solution...

for example, my code is,

```
class Bank
{
 private :
  list < Client*> clientList;

}

class Client
{
private :
 list< Account*> accountList;

}

class account
{
private 
 list< string> statement;

}
```

oh, i want to access statement in bank class! and i think how to access its...

1) making `list< Account*> getAccountList()` method in Client class and `list<string> getStatement()` method in Account.

but why list is private? umm, may as well public?

2) making list access method(umm, for example, pop and push?) in All Class..

i got 2. but it's terrible. I have a lot to do, and repeated similar function...

what is best way? it is way i never know?

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: Here is a possible solution : http://stackoverflow.com/q/3911098/79455

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to have accessor methods in each class returning const reference to the list:

```
class Account
{
   private:
      list<string> statements;

   public:
      const list<string>& getStatements() const
      {
         return statements;
      }
};
```

This is better than public because the returned list reference is not modifiable.

You could have methods returning const_iterator but then you must have methods on each class that return `begin`,`end`, and any other list operations you expect you might need.

Comment: @Johnpark: It seems Your only aim in posting the Q,was to get the implementation done and not understand the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should not access the private members of your class this is the basic OO concept. But in case you want to have a readonly access to your list just return the const reference of it like :

```
const list<Client*>& getList()const{
  return clientList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others mentioned, alternately you could return iterators to the beginning and end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Homework?

Suppose your program contains 20 classes that all access your Bank-class, different programmers have written these classes.

Then you discover that a bank-object does not have the clients in the list it is supposed to have.

Discovering the cause might take understanding all classes to see if one of them modifies Bank.clientlist (perhaps by mistake).

This is one of the reasons to encapsulate access to the clientlist.  There are other reasons for encapsulation and also some against them.

Kasper